# Set jQuery attr() on first image only

Tags: javascript, jquery

From past questions I know you can set a new attr() to existing elements on the page such as an ID to the images on the page, but in my case I want to set an id to only the first image. The other 4 for example are left without this ID being added.

With the below code, it keeps adding the ID to all images on the page.

```
<script>
    $( "img" ).attr( "id", "wp_featured_img" );
</script>
```

First **img** only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery :first selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) to achieve this.  You code would look like this:

```
<script>
    $( "img:first" ).attr( "id", "wp_featured_img" );
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah yep this works. Although just realised it now adds it to my logo because technically that is the first instance of 'img', is there a way to define the first 'img' within a particular div?

Comment: If you have a container for all your images (say it has attribute `id="myImageContainer"`), you can change your selector to become `$( "#myImageContainer img:first" ).attr( "id", "wp_featured_img" );`.

Comment: Spot on, got it now. Thanks. Will accept in a few minutes when I can.

To the others, thanks for your answers. All work although this response was simply the first so selecting this one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:first` selector:

```
 $( "img:first" ).attr( "id", "wp_featured_img" );
```

that selects the first matched `img` element.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$( "img" ).first().attr( "id", "wp_featured_img" );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rf0a00v4/1/) for the same